# Onclick event triggerd in onload

Tags: javascript

I create dynamic button in onload function.The button was created but the  **alertfunc** also call onload.

but I set the onclick event to trigger the **alertfunc**

```
window.onload = function () {
            var body1 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var t = document.createTextNode("Click Here");
            btn.appendChild(t);
            btn.setAttribute("class", "button");
            btn.setAttribute("id", "btnAssign");
            btn.setAttribute("name", "btnAssign");
            btn.setAttribute("onclick", "alertfunc()");
            body1.appendChild(btn);
}

func alertfunc()
{
   alert('test');
}
```

How can I prevent the **alertfunc** call onload ?

Comment: `func alertfunc()` <- you're sure that works at all ?

Comment: And -> https://jsfiddle.net/2dnbjn55/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/dohagoc/1/edit?html,js,output - after fixing the syntax error, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the function invocation is in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes to your code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var body1 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Click Here");
  btn.appendChild(t);
  btn.setAttribute("class", "button");
  btn.setAttribute("id", "btnAssign");
  btn.setAttribute("name", "btnAssign");
  btn.addEventListener("click", alertfunc);
  body1.appendChild(btn);
}

function alertfunc() {
  alert('test');
}
```

Hope this helps